# Edit Label is inactive in Glade

Tags: application-development, python, quickly, glade

I am using quickly to create ubuntu-applications.
I am follwing the tutorial presented in the line
http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/
When I add a toolbutton to the tool bar, I am unable to Edit the Label.
The Edit Label Option is greyed out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bug in the current version and is fixed in trunk as far as I know.
So, 2 options:

- Compile Glade from trunk and use that.
- Use this workaround: first add a new `Related action` (right above the label option) and set `Use action appearance` to `False`. Remove the action again if needed.